# How to execute two testcases in two different devices using Appium?

Tags: java, appium

I want to execute two test cases in two different devices but it is executing only in one device i.e of name 102.

1- I have given the devices name different in test case as well as Appium server.

2- The appium port is different.

Still, both the cases are running on one device i.e. the device name of 102. Suggest the code.
[TestCase1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NliVy.png)

[TestCase2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKVZ4.png)

Comment: It looks to me like both are identical, but it's difficult to compare since they are screenshots and not shown as code in your original post.  I also wonder how it works at all, because shouldn't the last part of your device name have a colon (for port number 5555) instead of a period?  Please edit your original post and put the actual code snippets there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Optimus.It's a new automation testing framework by TestVagrant technologies and it is used to run parallel tests on multiple devices.
Here is the github link to the template :

https://github.com/testvagrant/optimusTemplate

There are also a bunch of projects using this template.Do check them out for a proper understanding of how it works.